# In which parts of speech this word belongs to?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> The most  outcome would be 326 votes for Clinton to 212 for Trump.

I want to know that the bold word "likely" is in which parts of speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives). Adjectives are used to modify nouns. In your example, *outcome* is the noun that *likely* modifies.

> I suppose that might happen but it's not very **likely**. [*likely* modifies *it*]
>   Tickets are **likely** to be expensive. [*likely* modifies *tickets*]
>   The most **likely** cause of the fire was a cigarette. [*likely* modifies *cause*]

Moreover, the *likely* in your example is not simply an adjective; it's a [superlative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) adjective. The word *most* makes it superlative.

There's even [a separate article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/likely-and-unlikely) on the words *likely* and *unlikely* on Cambridge!